# What is the best way to perform OAuth2 authentication using akka-http?

Tags: scala, oauth-2.0, spray, akka-http

Akka HTTP and Spray provide an `authenticateOAuth2` directive, but [their documentation states](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0-M1/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/security-directives/authenticateOAuth2.html) that

> This directive does not implement the complete OAuth2 protocol, but instead enables implementing it, by extracting the needed token from the HTTP headers.

I also cannot find any libraries that implement OAuth2 for Akka HTTP or Spray.  Is there something I'm missing, or is this simply the state of these libraries right now?

Comment: In fact, there are just a few libraries out there for that. Have you check any of these? https://github.com/hasanozgan/spray-oauth or https://github.com/nulab/scala-oauth2-provider

Comment: @mayacr86 I referred to this project https://github.com/nulab/scala-oauth2-provider. but I  am not able to find the Main method, web server start code, endpoints(routes) code. I am requesting you to provide these codes (Main method, web server start code, endpoints(routes) code, and curl command to run the project).

Answer (score 3):

I think the biggest problem is that OAuth2 itself doesn't really tell you how the implementation details look like.

To quote [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.4):

> The token may denote an identifier used to retrieve the authorization
> information or may self-contain the authorization information in a
> verifiable manner (i.e., a token string consisting of some data and a
> signature).  Additional authentication credentials, which are beyond
> the scope of this specification, may be required in order for the
> client to use a token.

> Access tokens can have different formats, structures, and methods of
> utilization (e.g., cryptographic properties) based on the resource
> server security requirements.  Access token attributes and the
> methods used to access protected resources are beyond the scope of
> this specification and are defined by companion specifications such
> as [RFC6750].

For example you could use [JWT](http://jwt.io/) to validate a request or you could use the token only as an identifier and ask a service whether the token is allowed for that resource.

Depending on your OAuth2 provider the implementation can vary, so my guess is the framework can only provide you the common thing (extract the token for you) or it would have to implement all possible OAuth2 implementations, which seems not feasible at this point.

I personally have used [pauldijou/jwt-scala](https://github.com/pauldijou/jwt-scala) in the past, which you might want to take a look at.